# GWT JS *.nocache.js not generated

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, gwt

I'm trying to compile my gwt application. I'm having a parent project 'admin' and a maven module 'admin-app' with my web.xml *.gwt.xml admin.html.

Looks like:

- admin 
  package = com.admin
- admin-app

  - src/main/resources 
    package=com.admin file=admin.gwt.xml
  - src/main/webapp 
    ++ js 
    ++ admin.css 
    ++ admin.html 
    ++ WEB-INF 
    +++ jsp 
    +++ lib 
    +++ applicationContextx.xml 
    +++ web.xml

The problem is my entry point or my paths and defaults names.

I included

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="admin/admin.nocache.js"></script>
```

To to generate the JS code for my application.
But My problem is within my *gwt.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module SYSTEM "gwt-module.dtd">

<module rename-to='admin'>

    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>

    <!-- Specify the app entry point class. -->  
    <entry-point class='com.admin.client.AdminEntryPoint'/> 

    <source path='client'/>

</module>
```

My entry path is correct but I always get the error msg:

```
Loading modules
   com.admin.admin
      Loading inherited module 'com.admin.admin'
         [ERROR] Unable to find 'com/admin/admin.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
[ERROR] shell failed in doStartup method
```

Without the entry point I can successfully compile my project, so the problem is within the entry-point.

thx for any help :)

Comment: Try moving your admin.gwt.xml from `src/main/resources` to `src/main/java`. My gwt.xml files are all inside the the `src/main/java` and they work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this problem by renaming the module to `app` like the project-module, the *.gwt.xml to app.gwt.xml and also the path in my admin-html to `app/app.nocache.xml`. It's running know but the main idea was to use another namespace. So if anybody can help me there i would be very happy.

`app` should be named `admin`, for easier searching and so on.

thx :)